# How to run Macro when press enter automatically and paste in different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have created Macro to simply copy and paste, however i don't know...

1. How to activate macro if automatically if every time i press enter in "C13"
2. Every time when copy from "C13" and paste in sheet "AWB Scan Record" but vertically in different cell to create table, in below example it's paste in to Rance "A3" then next time it should paste into "A4" then "A5" and so on.

```vb
    Range("C13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("AWB Scan Record").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Tried simple macro but not worked

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Change: Keep Record of Each Scan

- This code needs to be copied to the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`) of the worksheet with cell `C13` (**Not** in `Thisworkbook` or a standard module e.g. `Module1`).
- There is nothing to run, it runs automatically: on each manual change in cell `C13`, its value is copied to the first available cell, the cell below the bottom-most non-empty cell, in column `A` of the other specified worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Me.Range("C13")
    If Intersect(sCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Me.Parent.Sheets("AWB Scan Record")
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    With dws.Range("A3")
        Set dCell = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If dCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dCell = .Cells
        Else
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    dCell.Value = sCell.Value
    
    MsgBox "Scan recorded.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it's proper working in PC, however it's not working when opening in mobile? Can you please advise.

Comment: VBA doesn't run in the Office web applications.